Plugin Leaflet-Search and Fetch call to GeoJson in Geoserver
I am connecting to a wfs service from my geoserver through the Fetch method in my code and it works correctly.
But I want to add this plugin by Stefano Cudini https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-search. I am only working with Leaflet, nothing else.
I have read the documentation and the examples he provides, and other examples on the internet, however I think it is not possible to work this plugin with Fetch.
I provide relevant part of my code, following the documentation.
The relative paths are correct because the "leaflet-search-master" folder containing the plugin files is in the same place as my html.
In this example I have placed the L.Search.Control inside my Fetch call, a suggestion from @Geographos in this post: Use leaflet search plugin with $GetJson function.

<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="leaflet-search-master/dist/leaflet-search.src.js"></script>


var puentes = 'http://---:---/geoserver/---/wfs?';
var defaultParameters = {
    service: 'WFS',
    version: '2.0.0',
    request: 'GetFeature',
    typeName: '---:---',
    srsname: 'EPSG:4326',
    outputFormat: 'application/json'
};
var parameters = new URLSearchParams(defaultParameters);

    //- - > FETCH call
fetch(puentes + parameters)
    .then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(data) {
        var fetch_puentes = L.geoJson(data, {
            pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
                return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
                    radius: 5,
                    weight: 1,
                    opacity: 1,
                    color: 'black',
                    fillColor: 'orange',
                    fillOpacity: 1
                });
            },
            onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {}
        }).bindPopup(function (layer) {
            return (`<b> Identificador.: </b>` + layer.feature.properties.id);
        });
        layercontrol_bases.addOverlay(fetch_puentes, "Puentes");
        fetch_puentes.addTo(map);
           
           // L.Search.Control inside Fetch call
                var searchControl = new L.Control.Search({
                    layer: fetch_puentes,
                    propertyName: 'id',
                    circleLocation: false,
                    position: 'topright',
                    collapsed: true
                });
                searchControl.on('search_locationfound', function (e) {
                    e.layer.setStyle({ fillColor: '#3f0', color: '#0f0' });
                }).on('search_collapsed', function (e) {
                    fetch_puentes.eachLayer(function (layer) {
                        fetch_puentes.resetStyle(layer);
                    });
                });
                map.addControl(searchControl);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log('There was a problem with Fetch call: ' + error.message);
    });


My html display all the layers and functions correctly but the console shows this error:
--- There was a problem with the Fetch request: L.Control.Search is not a constructor ---
I hope that all this I have provided is enough to find a possible solution.
